# Spotfire unexpectedly reading smartsheet date format incorrectly

Tags: spotfire, smartsheet-api

So I've been developing spotfire smartsheet connected dashboards for a while and use date types as format. Noticed spotfire is reading the dates strange adding extra 00s while in smartsheet date format is logical and was correct in dd/mm/yy format

Comment: Could you add more details about what you exactly want ? Because there are no question in your message.
Add a data sample or screenshots if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to a change in API response. Should be resolved now